# Accessing public function within extended HttpClass

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using an extended HttpClass so that I can apply headers and url paths dynamically. This is what it looks like:

**app.http.ts**

```
export enum Type {
  PREAUTH = 0,
  AUTH = 1,
  PRINTER = 2,
  TERMINAL = 3
}

@Injectable()
export class AppHttp extends Http {
  private typesOn: Array<any> = [false, false, false, false];

constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
    this.presetPetition(Type.AUTH);
}

presetPetition(type: number) {
    this.typesOn.forEach(t => (t = false));
    this.typesOn[type] = true;
}

request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options);
}

get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.get(this.updateUrl(url), this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
}

private updateUrl(req: string) {
  if (this.typesOn[Type.AUTH]) {
    return environment.apiURL + req
  } else {
    return req
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [
 AppHttp,
  {
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: httpFactory,
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  }
]
```

**http.factory.ts**

```
export function httpFactory(xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: 
RequestOptions): Http {
  return new AppHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions);
}
```

When I attempt to change the type of http request, I import AppHttp into the component/service, and call *presetPetition()* right before my http request.

I get a `No Provider for Backend Connection`.
So I understand that there can't be redundant provider imports (Http, and AppHttp), that must be that error.

How can I access a public function within an extended class? Or is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being violated the coding standard of angular. create a API service only for URL set and crud operation and for authentication extend the HTTP service of angular.

For common API:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BaseService {

  private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'charset': 'UTF-8' });
  private options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  // Get all
  getAll(url: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
  }

  // Count all
  count(url: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
  }

  // add
  add(url: any, entity: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(entity), this.options);
  }

  // Get by id
  getById(url: any, entity: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url + `/${entity._id}`).map(res => res.json());
  }

  // Update by id
  editById(url: any, entity: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(url + `/${entity._id}`, JSON.stringify(entity), this.options);
  }

  // Delete by id
  deleteById(url: any, entity: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(url + `/${entity._id}`, this.options);
  }

}
```

https://github.com/mdshohelrana/mean-stack/blob/master/client/app/shared/services/base.service.ts

For extended HTTP service:

http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/

I think It will be helpful to you.